# Declare const variable using wildcard

Tags: excel, vba, variable-declaration

I wanted to know if there's a possibility in declaring a const variable in Excel VBA using a wildcard, like in this example:

```
const myVariable As String Like "UP field*"
```

I need it because I have a cell field that can have several values but it always contains the substring "UP field", but sometimes it is like "UP field 5" or "UP field 3" or like that.

I just need Excel to find the first row of one table and that variable is the name of the cell that starts this row. It would be like my `A1` cell but it can be anywhere in the Excel sheet so I use a while loop to find that cell:

```
i = 1 
While ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) <> myVariable 'Looking for the first row     
  i = i + 1 
Wend
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand constants (which are [declared](https://docs.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-constants) and assigned a never-changing value, using `const`) vs. variables ([declared](https://docs.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables) with a specific [data type](https://docs.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary), with `dim`).  In neither case can you "automatically" restrict a certain custom value range, but you can accomplish the same thing programmatically.

Comment: I see, I understant ```const``` and ```dim``` but I thought it could be declared with wildcards too as in other programming languages. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a constant for this. `Range.Find` is a quick way to find the first of something and passing `xlPart` for the `LookIn` argument will satisfy the wildcard requirement. For example:

```
Public Sub FindFirst()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:="UP Field", LookAt:=xlPart)
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox rng.Address
    End If
End Sub
```

A while loop could've worked if you coupled it with `InStr`. I wouldn't recommend it, but I'm adding here for completeness:

```
Public Sub FindFirst2()
    Dim str As String, i As Long, rng As Range
    str = "UP field"
    i = 1
    Do
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1)
        i = i + 1
        If i > ActiveSheet.Rows.Count Then Exit Sub
    Loop While InStr(rng.Value, str) = 0

    MsgBox rng.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: How about `If i > ActiveSheet.Rows.Count Then Exit Sub`  for the second one?

Comment: Thanks @braX. I wasn't feeling too committed to the second solution so I didn't add that initially, but I appreciate your thoroughness. I've updated accordingly (although I also wouldn't have been put off if you wanted to update it yourself) :)

Comment: Thank you, I used the first solution you posted. I thought I could do it another way but it helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work for you:

```
Const myVariable As String = "UP field"

i = 1
Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) Like myVariable & "*" 'Looking for the first row
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

This will quit the loop at first cell **starting** with text `UP field`.

Comment: I think this solution would have worked too, I used the above one with the range.find but thank you so much! :)